# Is there a name for this type of integer programming?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Let $x_i$ be a decision variable, and let $c_i$ be the coefficient for the decision variable $x_i$.

An integer programming problem is where the goal is to:

$\text{maximize} \quad \sum_i c_ix_i$

$\text{subject to} \quad A\vec{x} \leq \vec{b}$

$\text{subject to} \quad x_i \geq 0, \quad x_i \in \mathbb Z \quad \text{for all} \ i$

where $A$ is a constraint design matrix, $\vec{x}$ is a vector of decision variables, and $\vec{b}$ is a vector of bounds.

In an integer programming problem, $c_i$ takes a scalar value.

Let us consider a separate problem below:

$\text{maximize} \quad f( \sum_i {C_ix_i} )$

$\text{subject to} \quad A\vec{x} \leq \vec{b}$

$\text{subject to} \quad x_i \geq 0, \quad x_i \in \mathbb Z \quad \text{for all} \ i$

where $C_i$ is a $p \times p$ matrix, and $f$ is a function that converts the matrix into a scalar, such as $\det$ or $\text{tr}$.

Is there a name for this class of problems?